# Get innerHTML from dynamically added script tag

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" id="embeddedScript">
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("id", "scriptData");
    script.src = "DynamicText.jsp";
    script.onload = function() {
        alert(x);
        alert(document.getElementById("scriptData"));
        alert(document.getElementById("scriptData").innerHTML);
        alert(document.getElementById("embeddedScript").innerHTML);
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**DynamicText.jsp**

```
x="Hello World!"
```

The first alert gives `Hello World!`

The second alert gives `[Object HTMLScriptElement]`

I expected the third alert to give the value of `x="Hello World!"` But it displays an empty value.

But for fourth alert I could see the entire text which was inside the script tag with an id `"embeddedScript"`

Reason?

Comment: what do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

The js script tag you created `scriptData` has no content between its tags. It is simply linking to a js resource to execute. It would come out looking like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="scriptData" src="DynamicText.jsp"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the text?

Comment: You could open up a file stream and read the contents of the `DynamicText.jsp` file, but you would need to do that in server side programming code, not javascript, since the file resides on the server.

Comment: This seems like an unrealistic example. Why would you need to retrieve the js text and not just execute it?

Comment: The thing is i may get plain text from `DynamicText.jsp`. In that case i may set the type of script element to text/plain. But i need to fetch the content. I may try that with an ajax request. But due to cross domain issues I found this the best way so far.

Comment: script tags won't work unless you ship valid js over the wire. the mime type doesn't really matter, the content does. if you need access to the source, you have to use ajax+cors

Comment: @Vicky Yes, you're best bet is to use ajax and get the file contents in server-side code, then give it back to the ajax call. Not sure the specifics to your cross-domain issues, but there should be ways around it..

Comment: @dandavis ajax+cors may fail sometime if the server does not allow. I had my personal experience with these issues. And also we need to fire XDomainRequest for IE8,9. Again it does not work when firing a request from http to https and vice versa.

Comment: @Vicky: then spit out json(p) instead of plain text, even if the "json" is just an encoded string instead of an object...